# Error fetching extensions. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND open-vsx.org

Tags: vsx, getaddrinfo, theia

Trying to add an extension to `Eclipse Theia Blueprint` but I keep getting this error

```
Error fetching extensions. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND open-vsx.org
```

[image]

Comment: Did you want to [add a vs code extension to Eclipse Theia Blueprint](https://theia-ide.org/docs/user_install_vscode_extensions/) or something else?